# Laravel raw query does not work

Tags: sql, laravel, select

I'm updating an old application to `php` and one of the crazy things is about one function which is getting an SLQ statement kept in the DB.. something like

field1 (SearchOrderLetterID), field2 (ShortName), field3 (SQLstatement)
   1

When I'm getting the sql to execute, I'm getting the next error "**Cannot access empty property**"

Example of query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ClosingDate,101) 
FROM dbo.Orders WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
```

Here is my code

```
public function getGenerateLetter($letterID, $orderID) {
    $letterFields = SearchOrderLetterParameter::where('SearchOrderLetterID', $letterID)->get();
    foreach($letterFields as $letterField) {
        $key = str_replace('##', '', $letterField->ShortName);

        if(preg_match('/@OrderID/', $letterField->SQLstatement))
            $query = str_replace('@OrderID', $orderID, $letterField->SQLstatement);

        $data[$key] = DB::select(DB::raw($query)); //here I'm getting the error
    }
}
```

Each row in DB has a different SQL Statement

How can I get the result of the query?

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: When I'm trying to execute the query. I added one the sql statements on the DB

Comment: Please paste the entire error message -- from what you've given, I can't tell if this is a PHP error or a MySQL error or what.

Comment: Also if you could paste a sample value of `$query` on the line you're getting the error, that would be helpful. The example you've given is before your `preg_match()` call.

Comment: Is the `getGenerateLetter` inside of a namespaced file? If so, do you have `use DB;` at the top of the file?

Comment: I'm getting the error here: $data[$key] = DB::select(DB::raw($query));

Comment: A query example is SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ClosingDate,101) FROM dbo.Orders WHERE OrderID = 199565, and the error you can check it out here http://prntscr.com/81ql0q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give an alias for this expression

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ClosingDate,101)
```

in this manner:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ClosingDate,101) AS ClosingDate
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it is fixed but I'd like to know why? When I'm executing the query in Navicat for example, is working without Alias. I can't understand why I have to give one.

Comment: explanation is deep in DB::select implementation. really dont want to dig, but u can do it your own